# Web framework for *not* creating websites?

Tags: python, web-frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended python library/framework for local web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543604/recommended-python-library-framework-for-local-web-app)

I am looking for a lightweight framework/webserver that will make it easy to develop web interfaces for some demon processes or some application that should have ideally be an desktop application.

Some examples

- To organize photo/music collections, move between folders, edit meta data of those etc,
- A simple to-do list/ Money manager/ Documents manager etc,
- A log/textFile viewer
- A page showing the status of my git repositories

I prefer server side to be python. I don't want to run a full webserver like apache. As this is going to be used similar to a desktop app, I dont need any security features that will prevent me from accessing file system or running any shell commands or accessing internet etc.,

Any suggestions?

Comment: This video recording of the Talk ["Web micro-framework battle"](http://pyvideo.org/video/983/web-micro-framework-battle) at PyCon AU 2011 might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2):

Check [bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)

Most frameworks will have built-in development servers, so you can still use django or some other. But if you are looking for something lightweight to do some quick project, bottle.py can be great

Answer (score 2):

[Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) is a good choice. It's a web toolkit more than a web framework. It's very mature, and is the basis of [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), a popular microframework.

I've developed a website using vanilla Werkzeug and it was really intuitive. It has an explicit feel to it. None of the RoR-style autoload-controller and folder logic, just a bunch of classes and modules that are really well-documented and useful.

Answer (score 1):

As well as cherry.py is a lightweight framework with full server.
http://www.cherrypy.org/

> ```
> CherryPy allows developers to build web applications in much 
> the same way they would build any other object-oriented Python 
> program. This results in smaller source code developed in less time.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Any Python web microframework running on any wsgi compliant Python lightweight web server will do. There are already questions on both here.